# JVM crash on Centos7

Tags: java, segmentation-fault, centos7, jvm-crash, jnienv

I am running a jetty server on centos7 and it keeps crashing with the below error

```
 # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
    #
    #  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fdd323ee698, pid=79411, tid=0x00007fd05bdfd700
    #
    # JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_222-b10) (build 1.8.0_222-8u222-b10-1~14.04-b10)
    # Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.222-b10 mixed mode linux-amd64 )
    # Problematic frame:
    # V  [libjvm.so+0x653698]
    #
    # Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
    #
    # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
    #   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
    #

    ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

    Current thread (0x00007fd044001800):  JavaThread "cron4j::scheduler[875ca3d006f7a65e29bf90fc0000016fc6274c4c6286cd54]::executor[875ca3d006f7a65e293583000000016fc678c0816e4418c5]" [_thread_in_vm, id=93353, stack(0x00007fd05bcfd000,0x00007fd05bdfe000)]

    siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x0000000000000000
Stack: [0x00007fd05bcfd000,0x00007fd05bdfe000],  sp=0x00007fd05bdfc4b0,  free space=1021k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x653698]
C  [libbCacheService.so+0x2068c]  JNIEnv_::GetObjectClass(_jobject*)+0x2e
C  [libbCacheService.so+0x1f400]  Java_com_applictaion_test_CacheService_buildCache+0x111
j  com.application.test.CacheService.buildCache([Lcom/application/test/db/CacheJNI;)V+0
```

The same code works fine on ubuntu. However, it keeps failing on Centos 7.

I have

```
gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 9.2.0
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 and jre1.8.0_65 same issue with both the JRE versions
Further more I use -XX:+UseParallelGC for GC.
```

As one can see the issue is from libjvm.so JVM environment and not an application problem.
Besides, the same setup and code on Ubuntu works fine, any idea what is going on with Centos 7?

Thanks

Raj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As one can see the issue is from libjvm.so JVM environment and not an application problem

No: the issue is most likely with `libbCacheService.so`, and not `libjvm.so`. I don't know what the origin of `libbCacheService.so` is, but given that google only finds this question when I search for it, I suspect that it's your application.

> Besides, the same setup and code on Ubuntu works fine

That is quite often the case: an application exhibiting undefined behavior works "fine" on one system, and crashes on another.

Your first step should be building `libbCacheService.so` with debug info, enabling core dumps, and checking from the core that whatever `libjvm.so` function is invoked from `JNIEnv_::GetObjectClass()` is called with correct arguments.

P.S. It looks (from `si_addr`) that `libjvm.so` dereferenced a NULL pointer. Possibly because you passed a NULL pointer to it as one of the parameters.

Comment: I changed UseParallelGC to UseSerialGC now I won't get any JVM crash, but it is having a slow memory leak.

Comment: Employed Russian, you were correct a object was passed as Null, its a coding issue and JVM issue. Thanks!